# Retrieving title and ID data from a webpage and saving in the excel file

Tags: html, r, extract, export-to-excel

I am looking to retrieve the titles and PMID (PubMed ID) records from the webpage and saving the same in the MS excel file. I tried using the `easyPubMed` library in R to extract, however, I am not able to obtain the same. Is there any library or package obtain this. Please assist me with this.

Example of the input data and expected output data is provided below:

**Code**:

```
    library(easyPubMed)
    my_query <- '"ACSL1" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase Long Chain Family Member 1" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase Long Chain Family Member 1" [ti] OR "Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase, Long-Chain 2" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain-Fatty-Acid–CoA Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Fatty Acid-CoA Ligase 2" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase 2" [ti] OR "Lignoceroyl-CoA Synthase" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 2" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase 1" [ti] OR "LACS 1" [ti] OR "LACS 2" [ti] OR "LACS-1" [ti] OR "LACS-2" [ti] OR "FACL2" [ti] OR "FACL1" [ti] OR "LACS1" [ti] OR "LACS2" [ti] OR "ACS1" [ti] OR "LACS" [ti] OR "Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase, Long-Chain 1" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 1" [ti] AND (acyl [ti] OR CoA [ti] OR fatty [ti] OR synthetase [ti] OR Palmitoyl [ti] OR ligase [ti] OR ACSL1 [ti]'
#### To count the number of PubMed IDs####
    my_entrez_id <- get_pubmed_ids(my_query)
    my_entrez_id$Count
```

**Input**

```
Webpage: https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/
Search String: "ACSL1" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase Long Chain Family Member 1" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase Long Chain Family Member 1" [ti] OR "Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase, Long-Chain 2" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain-Fatty-Acid–CoA Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Fatty Acid-CoA Ligase 2" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase 1" [ti] OR "Long-Chain Acyl-CoA Synthetase 2" [ti] OR "Lignoceroyl-CoA Synthase" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 1" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 2" [ti] OR "Acyl-CoA Synthetase 1" [ti] OR "LACS 1" [ti] OR "LACS 2" [ti] OR "LACS-1" [ti] OR "LACS-2" [ti] OR "FACL2" [ti] OR "FACL1" [ti] OR "LACS1" [ti] OR "LACS2" [ti] OR "ACS1" [ti] OR "LACS" [ti] OR "Fatty-Acid-Coenzyme A Ligase, Long-Chain 1" [ti] OR "Palmitoyl-CoA Ligase 1" [ti] AND (acyl [ti] OR CoA [ti] OR fatty [ti] OR synthetase [ti] OR Palmitoyl [ti] OR ligase [ti] OR ACSL1 [ti]
```

[image]

**Expected Output:**

```
dput(Output)
structure(list(Title = c("The 3-ketoacyl-CoA thiolase: an engineered enzyme for carbon chain elongation of chemical compounds.", 
"Potential influence of miR-192 on the efficacy of saxagliptin treatment in T2DM complicated with non-alcoholic fatty liver disease.", 
"Myosteatosis in nonalcoholic fatty liver disease: An exploratory study."
), PMID = c(32830293L, 32829627L, 32828745L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to collect and parse the results of your query. I Think something like this should do

```
my_entrez_id <- get_pubmed_ids(my_query)
my_entrez_data <- fetch_pubmed_data(my_entrez_id)
my_entrez_list <- my_entrez_data %>% 
  XML::xmlParse() %>% 
  XML::xmlToList() #turn the xml int an R List thats is easier to handle
my_entrez_df <- my_entrez_list %>% 
  purrr::map_df(function(x){ # use the map function from the package purrr to select the attributes that we need
    tibble(
      Title = x$MedlineCitation$Article$ArticleTitle[[1]], 
      PMID = x$MedlineCitation$PMID[[1]])}
    )
```

Comment: thank you very much for the solution. However, in the data frame, some of the titles are not printed completely. Is it possible to print the complete title names. I assume whenever there is a special character in the title, it skips the remainder names. See attached the image. [View Image](https://i.imgur.com/XJb5eCs.png)